# Add a new scheduled task from command line with "wake the computer to run this task" on

Tags: windows-xp, command-line-interface, scheduled-task, schtasks

I'm trying to add a scheduled task to start every day at a fixed hour even if the computer is in sleep mode.  In the Windows Scheduled Tasks Manager UI, there is a check-box labeled "Wake the computer to run this task".

How can I set this option with schtasks in cli?

The OS is Windows XP Pro.

My command right now is: `schtasks /create /tn "asdf" /tr asdf.cmd /sc DAILY /st 23:00:00 /ru System`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property cannot be set using `schtasks`.

See the *Power Saving* section [here](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html)

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no such parameter.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785(v=ws.10).aspx

As a workaround, you can create such a task from the GUI, export it, and import that to other machines. [Detailed description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497945/using-schtasks-from-the-command-line-what-parameter-will-wake-the-computer-from)